# Two forms, one PHP page and no action

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php page, which contains two forms. I'm using the first form to save the ComboBox selection. Here is a sample code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select onchange="form.submit()" name="selectionControl">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

$userSelection = $_POST['selectionControl'];
echo "<br>".$userSelection;

?>
```

If I submit the second form, the page reloads. Now I want to know the last `$userSelection`. But the variable is empty. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is there a reason for you need to seperate it in *two* forms? Just make one form out of it and it should work!

Comment: Easiest way is to simply make this one form (e.g. make the form tags wrap all fields).  Another more difficult way would be to have some javascript append the value of the selectionControl to the second form.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable is empty, because of the usage of twice form tag.
Why dont you use just one  ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to output the value of it in to a hidden field in the second form. Why not just make it one form though?

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select onchange="form.submit()" name="selectionControl">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="selectionControl" value="<?php echo $_POST["selectionControl"]; ?>">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

$userSelection = $_POST['selectionControl'];
echo "<br>".$userSelection;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 forms. The first one contains the select box, the second the submit button. The selection box isn't Patrick of the submitted form, hence the value isn't available as POST variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove your second `<form>` tag. It is unnecessary and prevents you from doing what you want to do (I assume, based on typical form uses, since it's not entirely clear what your end goal is).

Second, remove the `onchange="form.submit()"` from your `<select>` tag. If you want them to select from the dropdown, and provide their first and last name, submitting the form when they change the selection will prevent you from effectively doing that (they would need to intuitively know to enter the names first). Most users won't expect the entire page to refresh (from the form submit) when they select the vehicle manufacturer, and it's not necessary (again, assuming you're not doing something else with that information before they provide their names).